# link CSS not Found in [knp snappy]

Tags: symfony

I am currently working on a project (I use version 2.7 On Ubuntu 14.02) for managing statistics and report generation. According to the research I've done on google, I found the bundle "KnpSnappyBundle" for the realization of a PDF file.

the bundle works very already I get my .pdf file when I remove the links from my CSS files.

```
      <html>
        <title>templte PDF</title>
        <head>
    <link href="{{ asset('template/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
        </head>
        <body>
   here the content of document PDF
    </body>
    </html>
```

*this is the error when I add the link to my CSS file

> The exit status code '1' says something went wrong: stderr: "Loading
>   pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% [=======> ] 12%
>   [============================================================] 100%
>   Counting pages (2/6) 
>   [============================================================] Object
>   1 of 1 Resolving links (4/6) 
>   [============================================================] Object
>   1 of 1 Loading headers and footers (5/6)  Printing pages (6/6) [> ]
>   Preparing
>   [============================================================] Page 1
>   of 1 Done  Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
>   " stdout: "" command:
>   /home/Cros/Desktop/SecurityInfo/app/../vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
>   --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy579fd84622d630.80771275.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy579fd84622e172.46479589.pdf'.
>
> in vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php at
>   line 336   -
>       protected function checkProcessStatus($status, $stdout, $stderr, $command)
>       {
>           if (0 !== $status and '' !== $stderr) {
>               throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf(
>                   'The exit status code \'%s\' says something went wrong:'."\n"
>                   .'stderr: "%s"'."\n"
>                   .'stdout: "%s"'."\n"

So my question as to make these executable files on his server (I use the SF Server : 127.0.0.1) for the shaping of my PDF file and thank you.

Comment: Did you dump the assets? Please try to add more information to your post, like code samples.

Comment: I have not set the final template of my document. but my problem how to let the template to read the CSS file. notice I use that CSS file for every page and it works without problem.
Thank you for helping my friend